# Big O Notation for Nested Loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am trying to find time complexity for this Code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
  for (int j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++)
    for (int k = j + 1; k <= n - 1; k++)
```

My Attempt: 
We can write this loop in the form:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
```

Now Big Oh of this loop is O(n^5). Am I correct or doing some mistake?

Comment: Where do you get the '5' from? Also, use proper indentation to show that they are nested.

Comment: first loop run n times..   2nd loop runs n^2 times... 3rd loop runs n^3 times because they are all nested. But sometimes I think that its Big O notation is 1+2+3=6 i.e. O(n^6)

Comment: See trincot's solution below. Also, think about it this way: The inner-most loop of your second incarnation for the loop requires O(n) steps correct? Sure, it's invoked lots of times, but the inner most loop, when you are there, just takes n steps. The middle loop then invokes the inner-most loop n times. So this requires n times the steps required by the inner-most loop, which is O(n), so the second loop requires O(n^2). Finally, the outer loop invokes an O(n^2) operation n times, so the total will be O(n^3).

Answer (score 6):

The first variant of your code with a counter added:

```
int count = 0
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++)
        for (int k = j + 1; k <= n - 1; k++)
            count++;
```

This counts every combination of *(i, j, k)* with *0 <= i < j < k < n*. This corresponds to the number of ways you can pick 3 elements from *n* elements, without taking the order of them into account. There is [a formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) for that number:

*n(n-1)(n-2) / 3! = n<sup>3</sup>/6 - n<sup>2</sup>/2 - n/2*

The second variant:

```
int count = 0
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k <= n - 1; k++)
            count++;
```

... counts the number of ways you can pick 3 from *n* items, but where the order is important, and repetitions within the 3 selections are allowed. The number is quite easy to derive as *i, j, k* are independent and each can get *n* different values, so the total number is:

*n<sup>3</sup>*

Now they represent the same time complexity:

*O(n<sup>3</sup>/6 - n<sup>2</sup>/2 - n/2) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)*

This is because of the [properties of big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties):

> if a function may be bounded by a polynomial in *n*, then as *n* tends to infinity, one may disregard lower-order terms of the polynomial.

And:

> **Multiplication by a constant**
>   Let *k* be a constant. Then:
>   *O(kg) = O(g)* if *k* is nonzero.

Comment: That was the formula I was looking for. +1 but i m afraid that is all you will get because the OP is convinced that it is O(n**5)

Answer (score 1):

> Now Big Oh of this loop is O(n^5). Am I correct or doing some mistake?

No, this is not correct. The time complexity is `O(n^3)`.

In simple terms, you can think it off like this:

The maximum steps done in each for loop starting at `0` and reaching `n-1` making steps of 1 are `n`. So if you have two loops, one nested in the other then for each step you make in the outer loop you make `n` steps in the nested loop. Given the steps you will make in the outer loop is `n`, it's pretty evident that at the end you will make `n^2` steps.

Based on the above, you can easily draw that in the following case:

```
for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=n-1; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<=n-1; k++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

you will make `n^3` steps. So the complexity is of the order of `O(n^3)`.

Comment: first loop run n times..   2nd loop runs n^2 times... 3rd loop runs n^3 times because they are all nested. But sometimes I think that its Big O notation is 1+2+3=6 i.e. O(n^6)

Comment: @Knowledge32 Let's think about it based on the example I presented above. Let's isolate the two inner loops. How many times would this run? Apparently, `n^2`. If we put a piece of code whose comlexity is `n^2` inside a for statement, whose complexity is `O(n)` then the total complexity would be `O(n^3)`. Why? As we previously saw you would make n steps, since in each step you would make `n^2`, then at the end you would make `n* n^2`. So `n^3` steps.

Comment: So if your inner loop has 10 statements the complexity is O(n^16) ? Come on. Everyone is telling you O(n^3) from the start. @Knowledge32

Answer (score 1):

Are those loops nested? If so, you're on the right track with rewriting the loop like that to make things easier to reason about. Although I would give each loop a different iterator name than i to avoid confusion:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
    for (int b = 1; b <= n; b++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In fact you could rename these variables to whatever you want to make things easier to reason about. How about:

```
for (int street = 1; street <= n; street++) {
    for (int house = 1; house <= n; house++) {
        for (int room = 1; room <= n; room++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now,  the problem becomes, if I have to visit n rooms in n houses in n cities, how many rooms do I have to visit?

Hopefully you can see that the answer is n * n * n , i.e. n^3.

The shortcut way of getting to the answer is just to see you have 3 nested for loops from 1 to n, so the answer is n^3.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a doubt and you want to convince yourself just perform a little test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int count1=0,count2=0;
int n=100;

for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)

for (int j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++)

for (int k = j + 1; k <= n - 1; k++)
  count1++;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)

for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  count2++;

printf("count1 %d count2 %d n %d\n",count1,count2,n);
return 0;
}
```

result:

```
count1 161700 count2 1000000 n 100
```

- clearly, 2nd loop runs `100**3` times => O(n**3)
- first loop runs less because of the bounds, but it's still linear (no divide operations on bounds) => O(n**3) as well even if it is faster.

Comment: first loop run n times..   2nd loop runs n^2 times... 3rd loop runs n^3 times because they are all nested. But sometimes I think that its Big O notation is 1+2+3=6 i.e. O(n^6)

Comment: that's your own definition of complexity though.